# no operator >> matches these operands

Tags: c++, iostream, istream

I've been trying to overload the `>>` operator. I have a class that has two private variables:

```
Class Complex
{
 private:
    double real;
    double imaginary;
};
```

In addition I have a friend function that overloads the `>>` operator:

```
friend istream & operator>>(istream &is, Complex &c)
```

In the implementation of the function I've tried many ways to write into the variable of object `c` but I keep getting an error `no operator >> matches these operands`

I looked around and read that I need to write into a `reference` of the variable, so I tried the following:

```
istream & operator>>(istream &is, Complex &c)
{
using std::cout;
double &r = c.real;
cout << "real: "  << is >> r;
    return is;
}
```

However this still gives me the same error.
I'm slightly confused as I tried `is >> c.real` and didn't work.

On one of the answers in a similar SO question, someone suggested writing into a local variable and setting the object variable it, something like:

```
double d;
cin >> d;
setReal(d);
```

I'm trying to find a more simpler way to achieve this rather than using a method or setting the variable to a local one.

The solution could be a simple one, but I'm really just a beginner in C++, so please take it easy on me :P.

Test case:

```
using std::cin;
Complex c;
cin >> c;
```

Exact error message:

```
Error   1   error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?  At the moment, it's not clear exactly what the error message corresponds to.

Comment: I'm really not familiar with SSCCE. Do you mean you want me to show something like: Complex c;
cout << "Enter a complex number \n";
cin >> c;

Comment: You do know that the C++ standard library already have [complex numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a self-contained example code, along with the exact error message that you get when you try to compile it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes but it's an exercise from a book that suggested not to use the complex number from C++

Comment: @OliCharlesworth See edit (don't know if that's what you're looking for :S) Sorry if I'm being too confused.

Comment: Ahhh I solved it. It was because of cout << "real: "  << is >> r;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
cout << "real: "  << is >> r;
```

This is interpreted as

```
((cout << "real: ") << is) >> r
```

The problem here is that you can't have a line like this where you switch from outputting to `cout` and start reading from `is`.  A better way to do this would be

```
cout << "real: ";
is >> r;
```

That said, this is a *very bad idea*.  You should not have `operator >>` display a prompt, since it means that if you want to read in an object of your type from a file, every time you do so you will get the prompt "`real`" displayed on-screen.  You should have `operator >>` just read the representation, and explicitly prompt before reading if that's what you want to do.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just changed it to what you said seconds before you posted the answer haha. But thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line:

```
cout << "real: "  << is >> r;
```

Did you mean to use << instead of >> on that last one? Since you used >>, it's trying to write "is" into **cout**, but there is no overload of operator<< that takes a basic_ostream and a basic_istream.